# Firebase Analytics Dashboard's share report in pdf doesn't work

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a firebase app (with owner permission) that has enabled Analytics and It shows user data perfectly fine. When i try to share it as a pdf with Export document feature it only downloads a pdf with some static content of Google Analytics with the title "Welcome to Google Analytics" but not the analytics data that i have in the dashboard. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

It indeed seems that PDF export is broken. Sorry about that.

We logged in internal report to investigate the cause. I'll post back here when I know more about a fix, or have a status update otherwise.